# PHP check condition in a while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

This `$noOfSeat` variable value is 11;

This `foreach` returns **10, 8, 12.**

```
foreach ($_POST['vid'] as $key => $value) {
    $assign->get('vehicle', ['noOfSeat'], ['vid', '=', $value]);
    $dataSeat = $assign->result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $noOfSeat_p = $dataSeat['noOfSeat'];
}
```

Now I need to check

if in first loop **11** is less than 10 **If not** then shown an error message
then check the second loop if **11** < 18 (10+8) if true **then stop** otherwise show an error message and run the third loop...

Comment: So what the question is? Do you know about `break` and `continue` statements?

Comment: @NobbyNobbs yes I know but I need to show an error message. can't get the idea. The scenario is: 11 seats needed. This 10, 8 and 12 is no of seats of 3 bus. So I need 2 buses, not 3 buses.

Comment: Can I ask where the while loop mentioned in the title is?

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear for me, but as I understand, it's a possible solution:

```
<?php
$sum = 0;
foreach ($_POST['vid'] as $key => $value) {
    $sum += $value;
    if ($sum < 11) {
        echo 'ERROR MESSAGE';
        break;
    }
    $assign->get('vehicle', ['noOfSeat'], ['vid', '=', $value]);
    $dataSeat = $assign->result->fetch_assoc();
    echo $noOfSeat_p = $dataSeat['noOfSeat'];
}
```